# What are binary numbers that are equal to their length?

Tags: number-theory, binary

What are binary numbers that are equal to their length?

I am trying to find numbers where their value is equal to the length of their binary representation. They cannot start with zero.

For example:

```
1 = 1 and has a length of 1
10 = 2 and has a length of 2
```

Additional Thoughts:
Is there a name for numbers like this (maybe in different bases)?
I'm not sure if there are any more out there that exist.
Technically zero as "" is also true. It is nothing and has no numbers in it's representation, however, you can't write it. (so it's not real?)

Comment: I guess in any base, 1 is always going to work.

Comment: If the number has length $n$, then it is at least $2^{n-1}$.  So you need $2^{n-1}≤n$.  Therefore...

Comment: Well $0$ does have numbers in its representation; $0$. And yes $0$ is real and yes you can write it and in a way, it's not nothing. Just because "zero apples" means you have no apples, doesn't mean zero is nothing. If you have zero of something, then you have nothing. Zero itself is not nothing.

Comment: Yes, there is a name for such numbers; it is $1$.

Comment: It is true for all numbers in the [unary number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system).

Comment: @vrugtehagel: I was referring to zero being a possiblity, but I was stating that it's doesn't work. I probably should word that differently.

Comment: @Jens: That is true. Nice answer. I overlooked that system completely.